# Primary Key Violation

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am running in to a primary key violation. My target DE has 2 primary keys (ID+System) where there can be duplicate IDs and my source DE has primary key as ID. while update a column in Target DE based on matching ID, it throws me a primary key violation error

I cannot change the format in both source and target DE and have to so something with the query.

```
SELECT
a.ID as ‘ID’,
a.System as ‘System’,
a.Updated as ‘Updated’,
a.LocalId as ‘LocalId’,
‘TRUE’ as ‘IsDeleted’

FROM
[Contact Source] a Inner JOIN DeletedInvalid_Staging b on a.ID=b.ID
```

Could you suggest an solution for this?

Comment: Why don't you output Source field in your query, even though it is primary key in your target DE?

Comment: my mistake. I meant System.

Answer (score 0):

What type of method are you using to insert data into the destination DE? (Overwrite, Add, Update)

If Overwrite - you can try using a (Select DISTINCT * FROM [TABLE]) to make sure the result of your query is truly distinct and you don't have duplicate keyed records somewhere.

If Add - the data could already exist in the DE - try doing an Add/Update or just an Update instead or you can add an Where NOT EXISTS clause in your query...

> SELECT 
>   a.ID as ‘ID’,
>   a.System as ‘System’,
>   a.Updated as ‘Updated’,
>   a.LocalId as ‘LocalId’,
>   ‘TRUE’ as ‘IsDeleted’
>   FROM
>   [Contact Source] a 
>   Inner JOIN 
>   DeletedInvalid_Staging b 
>   on a.ID=b.ID
>   **WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 FROM [Your Destination DE] t1 WHERE a.ID = t1.ID AND a.System = t1.System)**

If Update - keep in mind, the result of the query you are inserting isn't inserting record by record - overwriting a previous record it just updated. The results have to be distinct.